# Model simplification (two way ANOVA)

Tags: r, anova, interaction, simplification

I am using ANOVA to analyse results from an experiment to see whether there are any effects of my explanatory variables (Heating and Dungfauna) on my response variable (Biomass). I started by looking at the main effects and interaction:

```r
full.model <- lm(log(Biomass) ~ Heating*Dungfauna, data= df)
anova(full.model)
```

I understand that it is necessary to complete **model simplification**, removing non-significant interactions or effects to eventually reach the simplest model which still explains the results. I tried two ways of removing the interaction. However, when I manually remove the interaction (`Heating*Fauna` -> `Heating+Fauna`), the new ANOVA gives a different output to when I use this model simplification 'shortcut':

```r
new.model <- update(full.model, .~. -Dungfauna:Heating)
anova(model)
```

**Which way is the appropriate way to remove the interaction and simplify the model?**

In both cases the data is log transformed -

```r
lm(log(CC_noAcari_EmergencePatSoil)~ Dungfauna*Heating, data= biomass)
```

ANOVA output from manually changing `Heating*Dungfauna` to `Heating+Dungfauna`:

```r
Response: log(CC_noAcari_EmergencePatSoil)

          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Heating    2  4.806   2.403  5.1799   0.01012 *  
Dungfauna  1 37.734  37.734 81.3432 4.378e-11 ***
Residuals 39 18.091   0.464
```

ANOVA output from using simplification 'shortcut':

```r
Response: log(CC_noAcari_EmergencePatSoil)
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)   
Dungfauna  1 41.790  41.790 90.0872 1.098e-11 ***
Heating    2  0.750   0.375  0.8079    0.4531    
Residuals 39 18.091   0.464
```

Comment: I think I have an answer for you, but can you please post your ANOVA output as text rather than as an image? (i.e., cut and paste from your R/RStudio session; it will look nicer if you put it inside a 'code block' delimited by triple backquotes

Comment: @jdobre's answer says about what I wanted to, except that I would seriously question your statement "[it] is necessary to complete model simplification, removing non-significant interactions or effects to eventually reach the simplest model which still explains the results." While this is broadly taught as statistical practice in biology, it is generally considered a **bad** idea by statisticians: see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection

Answer (score 3):

R's `anova` and `aov` functions compute the Type I or "sequential" sums of squares. The order in which the predictors are specified matters. A model that specifies `y ~ A + B` is asking for the effect of A conditioned on B, whereas `Y ~ B + A` is asking for the effect of B conditioned on A. Notice that your first model specifies `Dungfauna*Heating`, while your comparison model uses `Heating+Dungfauna`.

Consider this simple example using the "mtcars" data set. Here I specify two additive models (no interactions). Both models specify the same predictors, but in different orders:

```
add.model <- lm(log(mpg) ~ vs + cyl, data = mtcars)
anova(add.model)

          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
vs         1 1.22434 1.22434  48.272 1.229e-07 ***
cyl        1 0.78887 0.78887  31.103 5.112e-06 ***
Residuals 29 0.73553 0.02536         

add.model2 <- lm(log(mpg) ~ cyl + vs, data = mtcars)
anova(add.model2)

          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
cyl        1 2.00795 2.00795 79.1680 8.712e-10 ***
vs         1 0.00526 0.00526  0.2073    0.6523    
Residuals 29 0.73553 0.02536
```

You could specify Type II or Type III sums of squares using `car::Anova`:

```
car::Anova(add.model, type = 2)
car::Anova(add.model2, type = 2)
```

Which gives the same result for both models:

```
           Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
vs        0.00526  1  0.2073    0.6523    
cyl       0.78887  1 31.1029 5.112e-06 ***
Residuals 0.73553 29
```

`summary` also provides equivalent (and consistent) metrics regardless of the order of predictors, though it's not quite a formal ANOVA table:

```
summary(add.model)

            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.92108    0.20714  18.930  < 2e-16 ***
vs          -0.04414    0.09696  -0.455    0.652    
cyl         -0.15261    0.02736  -5.577 5.11e-06 ***
```